# Are there some popular science videos on computer algorithms to recommend?

Tags: algorithms, history

I am seeking for some popular science videos on computer algorithms for my last lecture delivered in this term. The topic of the videos includes but are limited to algorithm design, algorithm analysis, computational complexity, the application of algorithms, the history of algorithms (even computer science), the story about the people working on the field, and so on.

By ``popular science videos'', I am just ruling out the videos which are focusing on some specific theory and targeted at a special interest group. It will be better to meet the following specifications (not mandatory):

- produced by known university
- produced by known corporation, like BBC
- film or record, not just a speech given by one person
- lasts for more than half an hour
- amusing

Any recommendation will be appreciated.

Comment: Something bizarre http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywWBy6J5gz8 . And here something I liked very much http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dAyDi1aa40E

Comment: @A.Schulz The video is interesting but not suitable for my lecture. Thank you all the same.

Comment: plugging the result of the most plain U-tube search: [MIT Introduction to Algorithms (SMA 5503)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JPyuH4qXLZ0).